# Compare two source code files using EMF models

Tags: java, eclipse-emf

In my application I should compare two source code files to see if something has changed and then highlight those changes. For that i thought of using EMF compare. My application is a standalone application and is not used as a plugin or something similar. It should run without eclipse. Therefore I linked all the necessary libraries and tried to use EMF compare.

The problem now is that I don´t know how to build the two models that I have to use to compare the two source code files against each other. In the following code snippet I wrote as a first approach, the source code files are passed as files (Test1.java and Test2.java) but actually the source code of both files are stored in a string as the method parameters indicate.

So my question is basically how can I generate two models based on String that contain Java source code so that I can use these two models to compare against each other?

```
public void compare(String source1, String source2) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

    Resource.Factory.Registry.INSTANCE.getExtensionToFactoryMap().put("java", new ResourceFactoryImpl());

    XSDEcoreBuilder builder = new XSDEcoreBuilder();

    Collection<EObject> model1 = builder.generate(URI.createFileURI("Test1.java"));
    Collection<EObject> model2 = builder.generate(URI.createFileURI("Test2.java"));

    final MatchModel match = MatchService.doMatch(model1.iterator().next(), model2.iterator().next(), Collections.<String, Object> emptyMap());
    final DiffModel diff = DiffService.doDiff(match, false);

    final List<DiffElement> differences = new ArrayList<DiffElement>(diff.getOwnedElements());

    System.out.println("MatchModel :\n");
        System.out.println(ModelUtils.serialize(match));
        System.out.println("DiffModel :\n");
        System.out.println(ModelUtils.serialize(diff));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Java metamodel from [Modisco project](http://eclipse.org/MoDisco/), I think.
With it you can deserialize java files into EMF model and then compare.

[EMFText project](http://www.emftext.org/index.php/EMFText) also has Java model implementation.

Give 'em a try!

Comment: Thanks a lot for you're hint. I already tried Modisco and it looks really promising. The problem is that I'm not able to convert the source code String into a appropriate JTS project that is needed to use Modisco. And unfortunately I couldn't find any support or documentation.

Comment: I think you should see how menu item "MoDisco>Discover Java model from Java project..." implemented. There should be code calling modisco model loader for given set of files. I don't think it's a big deal to load from String instead of InputStream, if you had a code. Also AFAIK using EMFText's java model, you can use java files just as EMF Resources.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are using the wrong technology here.  AFAIK, EMF doesn't support a parser generator that you could use to parse Java source code and build parse trees as EMF models.

IMO, a better idea would be to use one of the existing Java parser generators (ANTLR, JavaCC, etc) and an existing Java grammar, then implement your comparison based on the parse trees that the generated parser produces.

Comment: Can you provide me with any more detailed documentation about that?

Comment: No I can't.  Google is your friend.